# Javascript regex matching paranthasis

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a json stream that needs to be decoded to extract complete json parts, Stream is in the form

```
{"a":1, "b":2}{"c":2,"e":3, "x":"eff"}{"3":4
```

and the regex `{([^}]+)}` extract complete groups as

```
{"a":1, "b":2}` & `{"c":2,"e":3, "x":"eff"}
```

the problem I have is **string data** may contain { or } but these will ALWAYS be enclosed within double quotes(")

Eg:

```
{"a":1, "b":2}{"c":2,"e":3, "x":"ab{cd}efg"}
```

is it possible to to have a regex that splits this to groups

```
{"a":1, "b":2}` and `{"c":2,"e":3, "x":"ab{cd}efg"}`
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iIXfgl/1)

Comment: Use a JSON parser.  This is the best long term answer.

Comment: You can't do this with a single regex in JavaScript. You'll need to do more parsing than you can with just a simple regex. (You can't do this with pure regex at all, but some environments have extensions that would enable it. JavaScript does not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following regex answers to question : `{(?:"[^"]*"|[^{])+}`
however if `\"` can appear inside `".."` the regex becomes `{(?:"(?:\\.|[^"])*"|[^{])+}`

Comment: Thanks, its passes all my test cases except {"foo":"}" is matched https://regex101.com/r/iIXfgl/2

Comment: this is because of backtracking, the prerequisite is that input should be well formed can be fixed adding `"` in negative character set `[^{]` : `{(?:"[^"]*"|[^{"])+}` or `{(?:"(?:\\.|[^"])*"|[^{"])+}`

Answer (score 1):

```
({(("|')[^{]+\3:(?:("|').+\4|\d+),?\s?)+})
```

This matches brackets, single and double quotes (making sure there is a pair of these), and the same on the other side of the colon, with the addition of numbers without surrounding quotes.

[See it working here](https://regex101.com/r/Hhq7e5/4)

If you don't want to match of single and double quotes, it can be simplified to:

```
({("[^{]+":(?:".+"|\d+),?\s?)+})
```

[See the simplified version](https://regex101.com/r/Hhq7e5/3)